# gnuplot. How to not print a point at the beginning of a graph?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to have just one point of a certain shape on the whole graph. For that goal, I'm using pi property:

```
plot 'a.txt' every 1000 using 1:3 with linespoints pi 30 title "A",\
'b.txt' every 1000 using 1:3 with lines points pi 30 title "B",\
'c.txt' every 1000 using 1:3 with linespoints pi 30 title "C"
```

The problem is, gnuplot prints the first point of each of these graphs and then prints another one in the middle of the graphs. I don't want to have that first point (actually, A, B and C start from (0,0) and that makes the graph look awful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to plot with lines then with points and set the first point in `every` clause:

```
plot 'a.txt' every 1000 using 1:3 with lines title "A",\
'a.txt' every 1000::2000 using 1:3 with points pi 30 notitle,\
.....
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I have already found another solution. Just put something like set yrange[0.1:].